# iPhone/iPad Get State of Wireless keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, keyboard, wireless

Is there any way in the iPhone SDK (not a jailbroken API, this needs to be AppStore-Compliant), to get the state of a connected wireless keyboard? e.g. which keys are pressed and which aren't? I have searched for this with google, but I am coming up short.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe if you tell us the larger goal you have, we can help you figure out what to do.

Comment: Basically, I want to use the wireless keyboard for some custom key strokes on my custom view (Ctrl + E = edit a value, etc.) these could all be done by touch, but it would be nice to be able to use the keyboard also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can tell whether a keyboard is *connected* or not, but you won't get callbacks for corded shortcuts. There is clearly a way to do this, because Pages supports keyboard shortcuts (Cmd-Z, etc), but it's not in the public SDK.